# Parsing gl.xml - inconsistencies?

Tags: opengl

The OpenGL [gl.xml](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-Registry/blob/master/xml/gl.xml) defines the the following command (example):

```
<command>
    <proto>void <name>glGetIntegerv</name></proto>
    <param group="GetPName"><ptype>GLenum</ptype> <name>pname</name></param>
    <param len="COMPSIZE(pname)"><ptype>GLint</ptype> *<name>data</name></param>
    <glx type="single" opcode="117"/>
</command>
```

Whereas the first parameter `pname` of type `GLenum` is taken from the group `GetPName`.

```
 <group name="GetPName">
    <enum name="GL_ACCUM_ALPHA_BITS"/>
    <enum name="GL_ACCUM_BLUE_BITS"/>
    <enum name="GL_ACCUM_CLEAR_VALUE"/>
    ...
</group>
```

However, not all constants are defined in `GetPName` (as of [Khronos](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/)), they exist in the *global* `GL-Enum` (enumeration of constants without an asociated group).

---

How do I handle these while parsing the xml? (I'd like to use the groups as seperate enums, as it'll add type-safety)
Some *Groups* are complete, others are mixed, is this an oversight or did I overlooked something? If the groups are inconsistent, what purpose do they serve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groups in the XML file are what I would call "non-normative" information. They're an attempt at codifying stuff spread over nearly 400 extension specifications and a dozen or so main specs + OpenGL ES. But overall, you can't really trust that they are correct.

If you know of an incomplete group, you could try to complete it and submit it to the appropriate GitHub repo as a patch. But other than by that, or by creating your own groupings of enumerators kept in a supplementary file, there's not much you can do.

Comment: Thank you! Thats unfortunate, and actually there are other inconsistencies like different types (GLuint, GLchar, GLubyte for strings) or duplicated entries. 
For now I'm naively parsing the XML and generate bindings for it, and every function I touch that differs from the Khronos-Wiki I'll keep track manually in a seperate file (and discard the item from the binding generator).

Comment: I read [this thread of the Vulkan vk.xml](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/210) where similar problems occur. I guess incrementally building an independant xml/json file and updating it every few years is my way to go.

Comment: @nonsensation: No, that's Vulkan thread is talking about a different set of problems. Namely, the problem of parsing through the document for non-C-like languages. vk.xml is very consistent about its enumerators.

Answer (score 2):

> However, not all constants are defined in GetPName

Recently faced with same problem. So, PR already merged.
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-Registry/pull/209

> How do I handle these while parsing the xml?

Check with spec and add your PR that fixes it to 
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-Registry